# Vertical histogram in C

Tags: c, loops, histogram

I am tasked in my homework to write a C program that takes 4 numbers from a user and prints out a corresponding histogram vertically (columns next to each other).

Example:
A = 5  B = 3  C = 1 D = 0

Output:

```
x  
x     
xx   
xx   
xxx  
ABCD
```

I am not allowed to use arrays or anything outside of simpleio.

I have the understanding that I need to think in rows, not columns, and that my starting point should be the row with the highest amount, and once it starts it keeps printing.

Other than that, I'm just looking for some sort of starting point or a hint of how to think about this properly. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: show us what you have done cuz nobody will do your homework, and your output does not makes sens at all?!!!

Comment: What do you mean by 'outside of simpleio'?  What is 'simpleio'?  Any idea why you're not allowed to use arrays, because arrays would make the work a lot easier.

Comment: Sorry about that. Simpleio is a library, the only thing I will be using it for is to obtain an integer from the user. Jonathan, I am not allowed to use them.  because arrays have not been covered in the class at this point.

Comment: Easy loop after seeking the maximum value from the input value.

Comment: You can presumably abstract the I/O into one piece of code that will call a function such as `void print_4_column_histogram(int a, int b, int c, int d)` which will do the printing.  You're going to need to establish the maximum value of the 4 integers, I think, and then for each line from that number down to 1, you'll arrange to print either a blank or an 'x' for each of 4 columns, followed by a newline.  Then print "ABCD" as the last line.  You might want to validate that the numbers are in the range 0..99, say, but perhaps that's in I/O issue rather than a problem for the printing function.

Comment: Thank you, Jonathan, along with everyone else. I'll make sure to be much more clear with future questions and will avoid formatting issues.

Comment: Please also search the SO site before. SO is meant as a knowledge base, not as a "I-am-stuck-in-my-homework" site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define print(VAR) (i<=VAR ? 'x' : ' ')

int main(void){
    int A=5, B=3, C=1, D=0;
    int MAX = 5;//int MAX=0;scanf("%d", &A); if(A>MAX) MAX=A;...
    int i;
    for(i=MAX;i>0;i--)
        printf("%c%c%c%c\n", print(A), print(B), print(C), print(D));
    printf("ABCD\n");
    return 0;
}
```